# Plone - getting and listing objects from member folder in a view

Tags: python, object, plone, directory, zope

i would like to make a view, which lists objects in specific folder (say root/Members/myname).
How to do this? I dont know how to reffer to folder. Something like:

```
items = []
folder = getFolder('/Members/' + myname)
for i in folder:
    if isinstance(news, i):
        items.append(i.title)
```

Hm?

Comment: Answers below are correct, sufficient for getting the objects themselves.  I would advise knowing circumstances in which you only need ids -- as folder.contentIds() will always be quicker for that case then using catalog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the catalog to list the contents of a given folder, by using the path index, with a depth limit:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
contents = catalog(path=dict(query='/root/Members/' + myname, depth=1))
```

See [quering the catalog](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/indexing-and-searching/querying-the-catalog/) for more information.

Alternatively, you could traverse to the folder in question and call the `getFolderContents` skin method on that:

```
memberFolder = context.unrestrictedTraverse('/root/Members/' + myname)
contents = memberFolder.getFolderContents()
```

The latter does the catalog search for you.

Comment: Should clarify that contents in the first example is a sequence of "brain" objects?  OP may not know distinction between catalog brain and object to which it refers.  objects = [brain.getObject() for brain in contents]  # or brain._unrestrictedGetObject() when appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```python
items = [obj.Title 
           for id,obj in context['test-folder'].items()
               if isinstance(news, obj)]
```

**More info**:
http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content/listing.html#listing-the-folder-items-using-portal-catalog